# The date was advanced / The date has been advanced

Tags: verbs, tenses, past-tense

What would be the difference between
"The date of the meeting has been advanced by one week"
versus
"The date of the meeting was advanced by one week"

The latter I've found in a dictionary. The former is what I would have said.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The former uses the present perfect and very strongly implies that the meeting has not yet taken place, whereas the latter uses the simple past and implies that it is over. As a speaker of British English I would not use the second version unless the meeting had taken place, but I notice on TV etc. that Americans often use the simple past where the action is still ongoing, e.g. "watch where you put your feet, I broke a glass", "your message was sent" (when it has just gone) etc.